# How to check a Json object name and or value in C# before POSTing to Web API?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API that accepts (POST) JSON object with multiple names with its corresponding value then adds it to my localDB. Here is the code that will POST that.

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostAddItems(Item ItemValue)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    using (ItemsDBEntities ItemEntity = new ItemsDBEntities())
                    {
                        ItemEntity.Items.Add(ItemValue);
                        ItemEntity.SaveChanges();
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK + "Item has been Posted!");
                    }
                }
                else
                {


     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Model state is invalid");
            }
        }

       catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I need to know how to check a JSON name before it I Add() it.

Comment: What do you mean under JSON name?..

Comment: Its the [
    {"JsonName":"John", "JsonName":"Doe"},
    {"JsonName":"Anna", "JsonName":"Smith"},
    {"JsonName":"Peter","JsonName": "Jones"}
]

Comment: Then your ItemModel must looks like this:
IEnumerable<UserModel>[] userArrays
And UserModel contains field JsonName.
Am I right?

Comment: @MaksimPavlov I didn't quite understand. My Model is using an Entity data framework .edmx.

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes, I see. So.. is Item has any properties/fields?

Comment: @MaksimPavlov I did not create a properties model. Just an entity. Do I need it, the property?